# How can I use `NODE_NAME` within an `options` block? - Jenkinsfile Declarative Pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

## Question: How can I use `NODE_NAME` within an `options` block?

I've tried the naïve solution to simply try and use `env.NODE_NAME`, but this evaluates to `null` inside the `options` block:

```
options { lock(resource: "${env.NODE_NAME}") }
```

The [Jenkins Pipeline docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) explained why this did not work:

> Inside a `stage`, the steps in the `options` directive are invoked before entering the `agent` or checking any `when` conditions.

So it's set to `null` in this context.

Next, I tried various methods to get `env.NODE_NAME` at `stage { steps {}}` level, and pass it up via a global Groovy variable.  However, this doesn't appear to work.

In the example `Jenkinsfile` below, the global Groovy variable `GLOBAL_NODE_NAME` acts as if it's a local variable within each `steps`, `step`, or `script` block.  Meanwhile, it acts as if it's a global variable within the `pipeline { stage { options {} }}` block.  The value set within the node's "heavyweight executor" context does not bubble up to the global Groovy script level.

### What I'm trying to do:

I want to use the `lockable-resources` plugin's `lock` syntax inside an `options` block to limit concurrent jobs.  If more than one job runs the `parallel` "`Run Tests`" stage, all RAM is consumed on the Jenkins agent node.  Therefore, I'm trying to lock a per-node resource to limit concurrent jobs on this particular node.

The minimal `Jenkinsfile` I'm using looks like this:

```
String GLOBAL_NODE_NAME = 'GLOBAL'
pipeline {
    agent { label 'ec2-node' }

    stages {
        stage('Get Node Name') {
            steps {
                script {
                    println("env.NODE_NAME='${env.NODE_NAME}'")
                    GLOBAL_NODE_NAME = NODE_NAME
                    println("GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}'")
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    println("DEBUG Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}'")
                    println("DEBUG Raw Groovy Variable GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='" + GLOBAL_NODE_NAME + "'")
                }
                sh "echo Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}'"
                // Do build steps here
            }
        }

        stage('Run Tests') {
            // Inverse order LIFO
            options {
                // Get NODE_NAME from the currentBuild b/c lightweight executor returns 'null'
                lock(inversePrecedence: true, resource: "${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}")
            }
            parallel {
                stage('Unit Tests') {
                    steps {
                        echo "Inside Steps block: GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}'"
                        script {
                            println("DEBUG Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}'")
                            println("DEBUG Raw Groovy Variable GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='" + GLOBAL_NODE_NAME + "'")
                        }
                        sh "echo Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}'"

                        // Do Unit Tests
                    }
                }

                stage('Integration Tests') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'echo this so example Jenkinsfile is valid'
                        // Do Integration Tests
                    }
                }
            } // end parallel
        }  // end Run Tests
    } // end stages
} // end pipeline
```

#### Output from above example job:

- Stage: `Get Node Name`:

  - `env.NODE_NAME='EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)'`
  - `GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)'`
- Stage: `Build`:

  - `DEBUG Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)'`
  - `DEBUG Raw Groovy Variable GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)'`
  - ```
     echo Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME=EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) -
     Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)

     Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME=EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)
    ```
- Stage: `Run Tests`:

  - **Note:** Inside `options` block, `echo`, `println`, are not available... but we can see the output in the resource's name on the `https://<jenkins-host-here>/lockable-resources/` page:

    - `GLOBAL_NODE_NAME` is set to "`GLOBAL`", so the `stage` => `step` assignment did **not** work!
    - [image: Lockable Resources shows the value is still set to GLOBAL]
    - **Lockable Resources shows that the value of `resource` is still set to `GLOBAL`!**
  - Parallel Stage: `Unit Tests`

    - `Inside Steps block: GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)'`
    - `DEBUG Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)'`
    - `DEBUG Raw Groovy Variable GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)'`
    - ```
         + echo Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME=EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)

         Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME=EC2 (EC2-Jenkins) - Pipeline Builder (i-feeb1ec0de5caff01d)
      ```

## EDIT: Here's the final working solution

Thanks to @AdamSmith's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122586/645491), it got me started in the right direction.  Here is a skeleton of the final `Jenkinsfile` structure that worked:

```
/* groovylint-disable DuplicateStringLiteral */
/* groovylint-disable-next-line CompileStatic */
String debugBegin = '============================== DEBUG ENV =============================='
String debugEnd = '============================== END DEBUG =============================='
/* groovylint-disable NestedBlockDepth */
/* groovylint-disable-next-line CompileStatic */
pipeline {
    agent { label 'ec2-node' }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                   // Evaluates in 'heavyweight' executor context
                    println("Running on env.NODE_NAME='${env.NODE_NAME}'") // env.NODE_NAME works here
                }
                // Do build steps here
            }
        }

        stage('Run Tests') {
            options {
                /*
                Note: Cannot get NODE_NAME from this context!
                options is evaluated inside 'lightweight' executor, so currentBuild returns 'null'
                and any other method trying to pass env.NODE_NAME, or
                NODE_NAME up from the node / 'heavyweight' executor context did not work!

                lock(inversePrecedence: true, resource: "cannot-get-node-name") // Anything I tried here did not work!
                This context executes on jenkins master, and I could not find a way to pass the value back from a node
                */
                timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES')
            }
            steps {
                // Inverse order LIFO
                // lock NODE_NAME b/c parallel tests are RAM intensive
                lock(inversePrecedence: true, resource: "${NODE_NAME}") {
                    script { // hack so parallel syntax is made available here
                        parallel Test: { // map: {} syntax to pass to scripted-pipeline 'parallel'
                            stage('Test') {
                                try { // Switched from post { always {}} to => try {} finally {} here
                                    // because syntax did not work otherwise
                                    echo "Inside Steps block: NODE_NAME='${NODE_NAME}'"
                                    println("DEBUG Interpolation NODE_NAME='${NODE_NAME}'")
                                    println("DEBUG Raw Groovy Variable NODE_NAME='" + NODE_NAME + "'")
                                    sh "echo Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${NODE_NAME}'"
                                    echo "${debugBegin}"
                                    sh 'env' // STAGE_NAME is now 'Test'
                                    echo "${debugEnd}"
                                    sh 'make test'
                                    echo 'Tests Succeeded!'
                                }
                                finally {
                                    junit '**/path/to/test-reports/*.xml'
                                    sh 'make cleanup'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        IntegrationTests: {
                            stage('Integration Tests') {
                                try {
                                    echo "${debugBegin}"
                                    sh 'env' // STAGE_NAME is now 'Integration Tests'
                                    echo "${debugEnd}"
                                    sh 'make integration'
                                    echo 'Integration Tests Succeeded!'
                                }
                                finally {
                                    sh 'make cleanup'
                                }
                            }
                        } // end parallel map
                    } // end script
                } // end lock NODE_NAME
            } // end steps
        } // end stage Run Tests
    } // end stages
} // end pipeline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, but since `lock` is *also* available in the `steps` block, you could handle it that way. Due to the nature of these things, you'll probably have to use a `script` escape hatch in here to continue being parallel (sorry)

```
stage('Run Tests') {
    steps {
        // Inverse order LIFO
        lock(inversePrecedence: true, resource: "${NODE_NAME}") {
            script {
                parallel [
                    'Unit Tests': {
                        echo "Inside Steps block: NODE_NAME='${NODE_NAME}'"
                        println("DEBUG Interpolation NODE_NAME='${NODE_NAME}'")
                        println("DEBUG Raw Groovy Variable NODE_NAME='" + NODE_NAME+ "'")
                        sh "echo Shell string Interpolation GLOBAL_NODE_NAME='${GLOBAL_NODE_NAME}'"
                    },
                    'Integration Tests': {
                        sh 'echo this so example Jenkinsfile is valid'
                    }
                ]
            } // end script
        } // end lock
    }  // end steps
} // end stage 'Run Tests'
```

Comment: N.B. my syntax for the parallel step might be somewhat wrong. It's been a while!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I just tried this syntax, and it does acquire the lock using the correct `NODE_NAME` value.  However, it then fails and throws this exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@6bfe930b`

Comment: I tried the `parallel [ 'Unit Tests': {}, 'Integration Tests': {} ]` syntax, and that one gave me `WorkflowScript: 54: Unsupported map entry expression for CPS transformation in this context @ line 54, column 36.`

I should probably rename my file to `Jankinsfile` because getting the syntax to work is so janky. 

Comment: @TrinitronX looks like the expected syntax is `parallel UnitTests: { /* that block */ }, IntegrationTests: { /* the other block */}`

Comment: Thanks!  That syntax form does appear to work to give a way to lock the parallel steps.  Unfortunately, now I'm running into a different issue because the parallel stages depend on `STAGE_NAME` being different across each parallel stage `Unit Tests`, vs. `Integration Tests`.    The parallel syntax without nested `stage()`s ends up with `STAGE_NAME=Run Tests` across all of them.  So, unfortunately the test stages using `docker-compose` are relying on a unique `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=${BUILD_TAG}-${EXECUTOR_NUMBER}-${STAGE_NAME}`. To avoid container namespace conflicts.  Now they are conflicting.

Comment: So as it turns out, I was able to wrap the contents of each `parallel Test: { /* tests here */ }, IntegrationTests: { /* integration tests here */ }` with a named `stage` block, and it's now working again with unique `STAGE_NAME`s!  For example, I had to use: `parallel Test: { stage('Test') { /* tests here */ } }, IntegrationTests: { stage('Integration Tests') { /* integration tests here */ } }`.  It's a bit wordy and feels more like a hack, but at least it works!  Jenkins declarative pipeline syntax sure is rigidly limiting sometimes... but at least the `script { parallel {} }` works now!

Comment: Another caveat that I ran into with this syntax was getting some `post` JUnit & cleanup/teardown steps to work again.  The omitted parallel stage contents had some blocks like: `post { always { junit '**/path/to/test-reports/*.xml' ;  sh 'make cleanup' } }`
When nested under `script { parallel { }}`, the `post` DSL syntax is not available.  The `always` keyword was available, but did not operate as expected.  I had to switch to using the scripted pipeline style: `try { }  finally { }` to get the `post` actions to work again.